# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [4,2] vs. [2,3] [Op:Mul]

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

Estoy intentando aprender `Tensorflow 2.0` , intentando hacer un perceptron multicapa.

Al intentar multiplicar dos matrices o tensores que tienen tamaño 4x2 y 2x3 me dice que tienen tamaños incompatibles. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import tensorflow as tf

#Entrada
e = tf.constant([[0.,0.],
            [0.,1.],
            [1.,0.],
            [1.,1.]],tf.float32)

#Salida deseada
d = tf.constant([[0.],
            [1.],
            [1.],
            [0.]],tf.float32)

#Capa 1
pesos1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([2,3] , minval=-0.5 , maxval=0.5 , dtype=tf.float32 ))
bias1 =  tf.Variable( tf.random.uniform( [3]   , minval=-0.5 , maxval=0.5 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
s1 = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(e*pesos1+bias1)
```

**¿Cuál es el error?**

Answer (score 0):

`tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits()` no sirve para realizar una multiplicación matricial. Si quieres multiplicar matrices en tensorflow, puedes usar el `@` al igual que en `Numpy` y después sumar

En este caso cogiendo las partes fundamentales de tu código sería así:

```
#Multiplicamos y sumamos
(e @ pesos1) + bias1
```

También se puede hacer **con las funciones de `Tensorflow`**

```
#Hacemos la multiplicación con matmul() y después sumamos con add()
tf.add(tf.linalg.matmul(e, pesos1), bias1)
```

En ambos la **salida** es igual:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.4995885 , -0.37387633,  0.443457  ],
       [-0.9218788 , -0.3137734 ,  0.66483474],
       [-0.0700382 , -0.84479177,  0.7386017 ],
       [-0.49232852, -0.78468883,  0.9599794 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

### Le entropia cruzada con sigmoide

`tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits()`
**Es una función de perdidas de clasificación**, que como su nombre indica sirve para medir la **información** (entropia) y después se aplica la función sigmoide para decicir una clase.

Pero eso no es lo que estás buscando en esta parte de la red neronal, lo que tu buscas es calcular la multiplicación de los pesos más un bias. Es decir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que se consigue como está indicado arriba.